# How to call function whose argument info is in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic

I am doing this exercise for kicks while trying to understand Mypy code, here we go:

I have dynamically imported a function `func` and created a dict `argument_info` having:

- keys as argument names (collected using `inspect`), and
- values as corresponding values gathered at runtime.

For simplicity let us assume that `func`'s arguments have no default values, *args or **kwargs at the moment.

Then how do I call the function `func` with values in `argument_info`?

---

Sample implementation:

```
# file my_module.py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

-------------------------------

# file main.py
argument_info = {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 20,
    "garbage": "irrelevant data"
}
func = getattr(my_module, 'add')
# how to do the following line dynamically
func(info['a'], info['b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


# file main.py

argument_info = {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 20
}

print(add(**argument_info))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# file my_module.py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

-------------------------------

# file main.py
argument_info = {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 20,
    "garbage": "irrelevant data"
}
func = getattr(my_module, 'add')
args = func.__code__.co_varnames
info = {k:v for k, v in argument_info.items() if k in args}
print func(**info)
```